# Looking for a Clipboard Viewer (not a clipboard manager)

Tags: mac, software-recommendation

I need a simple permanently visible window that simply shows whatever is in the clipboard (text, graphic, or file). The window should not auto-size itself when the clipboard contains a large graphic (like Finder's clipboard viewer).
Also, Finder's clipboard viewer window hides when Finder loses focus.

If the clipboard contains formatted text it should show the text formatted, if it contains unformatted text it should show the text unformatted. And it should automatically start at login.

I tried searching via Google and in the Mac App Store, but all I found are Clipboard managers which offer a lot of functionality I don't need but don't have a way to just show the clipboard.

Does anybody know about a simple Clipboard Viewer?

Comment: Found this but never tried : https://sindresorhus.com/pasteboard-viewer

Comment: @tama Thanks for your comment and link. It is ALMOST what I need (it even has a Stay-On-Top feature) - except the window has a minimal size of 500*352 pixel. I would be nice if the window could be made smaller.

Comment: Also, the window position is not restored after a restart. The last window position should be automatically restored after a restart!

Comment: You probably can't expect solutions to be perfect, it also would help if you list requirements directly in the question (and not only mention them in the comments).

Comment: I will try to recompile the source code with my changes.

Comment: Pasteboard Viewer also has the very nice feature of showing all formats in the clipboard. For example, when I copy a text from a website in my web browser, Pasteboard Viewer shows these two formats: `pbublic.html` and `public.utf8-plain-text`. This allows me to get the source code of the selected web page text.